# Google Direction Api Enterprise

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am converting our Googleapis geocode, directions,rev-geocode to enterprise version, using the following code to sign the request.

```
+(NSString*)sampleRequestSigning:(NSString*)url{

NSString *key = @"KEY";

// Stores the url in a NSData.
NSData *urlData = [url dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// URL-safe Base64 coder/decoder.
GTMStringEncoding *encoding =
[GTMStringEncoding rfc4648Base64WebsafeStringEncoding];

// Decodes the URL-safe Base64 key to binary.
NSData *binaryKey = [encoding decode:key];

// Signs the URL.
unsigned char result[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1,
       [binaryKey bytes], [binaryKey length],
       [urlData bytes], [urlData length],
       &result);
NSData *binarySignature =
[NSData dataWithBytes:&result length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

// Encodes the signature to URL-safe Base64.
NSString *signature = [encoding encode:binarySignature];
NSLog(@"The final URL is: http://maps.googleapis.com/%@&signature=%@", url,
      signature);
return signature;}
```

Now the issue is when i am hitting the URL http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York&client=CLIENT_ID&signature=TWjoq7aKH7afd5cbbH949JQjPkw=

Following error is coming

Unable to authenticate the request. Provided 'signature' is not valid for the provided client ID, or the provided 'client' is not valid.
The signature was checked against the URL: /maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York&client=CLIENT_ID
If this does not match the URL you requested, please ensure that your request is URL encoded correctly. Learn more: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth

Kindly Help ???

Comment: Are you perhaps passing your signing key as the signature?

Comment: Yes Andy, CryptoKey and ClientID are properly generated from work account